# Not able to queue any jobs in jenkins, the jobs are keep in queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

**Environment details:**

```
Server - Windows 10
Jenkins version - 2.7.4
```

**Steps caused the issue:**
After building a Java jar file, I tried to execute the jar in the same node (which is master node itself)
Following is the command line which I executed through jenkins job
start "xyz" java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dit myjar.jar

**Issue:**
After running the above commandline, no jobs are allowed to queue. All jobs are waiting for executor then.